# Button only clickable when visible

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok i want my button to only be clickabe once it is visibe, it is invisible til you win the game(1 score of pong)
here is what i have

```
var buttonsStates:Object = {
    "scoreBoard_W" : false
};

function checkVisibility () {
    for (var scoreBoard_W:String in buttonsStates) {
        if(visible == true)
        {
            scoreBoard_W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
            function goto3(Event:MouseEvent)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1,"Menu");
            }
```

and here is the error: `Pong, Layer 'Pong', Frame 2, Line 129   1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type String.`

im not sure what it means, or if im on the right track any help is apperciaed
Here is all of the code

```
stop();
var buttonsStates:Object = {
    "scoreBoard_W" : false
};

var ballSpeedX:int = -3;
var ballSpeedY:int = -2;
var cpuPaddleSpeed:int = 3;
var playerScore:int = 0;
var cpuScore:int = 0;
scoreBoard_W.visible = false;
scoreBoard_L.visible = false;
init();

function init():void
{
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}

function calculateBallAngle(paddleY:Number, ballY:Number):Number
{
    var ySpeed:Number = 5 * ((ballY - paddleY) / 25);
    return ySpeed;
}

function updateTextFields():void
{
    playerScoreText.text = ("Player Score: " + playerScore);
    cpuScoreText.text = ("CPU Score: " + cpuScore);
}

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    if (playerPaddle.hitTestObject(ball) == true)
    {
        if (ballSpeedX < 0)
        {
            ballSpeedX *=  -1;
            ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(playerPaddle.y, ball.y);
        }
    }
    else if (cpuPaddle.hitTestObject(ball) == true )
    {
        if (ballSpeedX > 0)
        {
            ballSpeedX *=  -1;
            ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(cpuPaddle.y, ball.y);
        }
    }

    if (cpuPaddle.y < ball.y - 10)
    {
        cpuPaddle.y +=  cpuPaddleSpeed;
    }
    else if (cpuPaddle.y > ball.y + 10)
    {
        cpuPaddle.y -=  cpuPaddleSpeed;
    }

    playerPaddle.y = mouseY;

    if (playerPaddle.y - playerPaddle.height / 2 < 0)
    {
        playerPaddle.y = playerPaddle.height / 2;
    }
    else if (playerPaddle.y + playerPaddle.height/2 > stage.stageHeight)
    {
        playerPaddle.y = stage.stageHeight - playerPaddle.height / 2;
    }

    ball.x +=  ballSpeedX;
    ball.y +=  ballSpeedY;



    if (ball.x <= ball.width / 2)
    {
        ball.x = ball.width / 2;
        ballSpeedX *=  -1;
        cpuScore++;
        updateTextFields();
    }
    else if (ball.x >= stage.stageWidth-ball.width/2)
    {
        ball.x = stage.stageWidth - ball.width / 2;
        ballSpeedX *=  -1;
        playerScore++;
        updateTextFields();
    }


    if (ball.y <= ball.height / 2)
    {
        ball.y = ball.height / 2;
        ballSpeedY *=  -1;
    }
    else if (ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2)
    {
        ball.y = stage.stageHeight - ball.height / 2;
        ballSpeedY *=  -1;
    }

    if (playerScore >= 1)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        scoreBoard_W.visible = true;
    }
    if (cpuScore >= 1)
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        scoreBoard_L.visible = true;
    }
}

Mouse.hide();
mywelcome.text = "Good Luck, " + myName;
function checkVisibility () {
    for (var scoreBoard_W:String in buttonsStates) {
        if(visible == true)
        {
            scoreBoard_W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
            function goto3(Event:MouseEvent)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1,"Menu");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is that you're attempting to add an event listener to a string (`scoreBoard_W`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line

```
scoreBoard_W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
```

As you using `for (var scoreBoard_W:String in buttonsStates){...}` inside definition of function  `function checkVisibility () {...}` you declare local String-type variable which block your access to button with same name.
Changing

```
scoreBoard_W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
```

to

```
this.scoreBoard_W.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goto3);
```

will do the trick.